# dynamic index for an expression condition such as While, If etc

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

Talking about a`for-loop`, I want a dynamical condition within a `for-loop`. To make it more clear, here is what I have for you as my code:

```
FileOutputStream Fcategorize = new FileOutputStream(write, true);

FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(wrote);

BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

String line;

for (int i = 0; (line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null; i++) {

    if ("this2".equals(line)) {
        while (!"this3".equals(line = bufferReader.readLine())) {
            Fcategorize.write(line.toLowerCase().getBytes());
            Fcategorize.write(
                    System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
        }
    }

}
```

However, what I want is that both `this2` and `this3` change their integer property in each iteration, regarding to the value of `i`. How is it possible?

*EDIT:*

Sample File content:

```
this2
primarygames
storybooks
bookshelf.htm
this3
classzone
books
research_guide
page_build.cfm
this4
grandmasandy
books-info.html
this5
soiwasthinkingaboutadoption
free_book.html
this6
slcpd
c0ntent
uploads
activity-book.pdf
this7
```

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like to use `"this"+i` instead of "this2"? Then, use it, or `"this"+(i+1)`.

Comment: that is correct. but if I use `"this"+i`then it will not work. so your suggestion is to use `"this"+(i+1)`?

Comment: @laune  that is correct. but if I use "this"+ithen it will not work. so your suggestion is to use "this"+(i+1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean solution might use a method to calculate the string to be matched, based on the current line or group number.

```
static String header( int i ){
    return "this" + (i+2);     // "this2" for i == 0 
}
static String body( int i ){
    return "this" + (i+3);     // "this3" for i == 0 
}
```

and the read loop becomes

```
String line = bufferReader.readLine();
for(int i = 0; line != null; i++){
    if( header(i).equals(line)){
        while( (line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null &&
               ! body(i).equals( line ) ){
            Fcategorize.write(...);
            Fcategorize.write(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've added a check for EOF in the inner loop as well.

If you do want to have the string composition in line, use

```
   if( ("this" + (i+2)).equals( line ) ){...}
```

or, since line is never null if guarded properly

```
   if( line.equals( "this" + (i+2) ) ){...}
```

The arithmetic plus must be given higher priority; otherwise it'll concatenate to "this02", "this12" etc.

**Edit** The algorithm is inherently dangerous as it may enter an infinite loop if the first line doesn't contain "this2". It would be better to read in a single loop and test the line, to see where you are.

```
String line;
int expect = 0;
int body = 0;
while( (line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null ){
    if( line.equals( header(expect) ) ){
        body = expect;
        expect++;
    } else if( body > 0 ) {
        Fcategorize.write(...);  // process body 
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, it writes nothing into the file. For your ease to check your code, I added a sample of data in my file in my question as an Edit.

Comment: i guess i know why it does not work. every time there is a mismatch, the value of `i` changes while it should not, until it reaches the end of file and then for next iteration, it does the same thing for `this3` and `this4` etc. I do not know if you got me.

Comment: I know what you mean - I think I simply overlooked the "not" operator; fixed now. - The data sample helps...

Comment: but why it does not write the lines between each `"this"+i` yet?

Comment: to be more precise, for me, it only iterates once and then finishes.

Comment: Of course: you are reading too often, so the next header is skipped. See my change - the data sample *really* helps.

Comment: but what i want is to write between each `this` in each iterate, do something with them and then between next two `this`.

Comment: yeay. now it is working. the problem was at `string line`, right?

Comment: The read in the for statement skipped the header of the next group, so it never matched again. - Reading groups of lines is best done by a single loop which processes the next line according to state.

Comment: understood. But what I did not get is that why modification to `String line;` fixed the problem while it is placed out of the loop? That made me a little confused.

Comment: The readLine before the loop is the kickoff: reading of the first line. - The algorithm is very dangerous now: if there isn't a line "this2", it'll run into an infinite loop. See the revised version I've edited into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> what I want is that both this2 and this3 change their integer property in each iteration, regarding to the value of i.

So you need to create the string `this2` and `this3` dynamically based on `i` inside the loop.

Hence, try the following:

```
String thisWithIterator;
//... some code
for (int i=0;(line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null;i++) {

    thisWithIterator = "this"+(i+2);

    if(thisWithIterator.equals(line)) {
    //... some code   

    thisWithIterator = "this"+(i+3);

    while(!thisWithIterator.equals(line=bufferReader.readLine())) {
    //... rest of the codes goes here
```

Comment: unfortunately, it writes nothing into the file. For your ease to check your code, I added a sample of data in my file in my question as an Edit.